# Get Margin from draggable child element in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get the `margin-left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` of a draggable element? For example I found [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/607pnzuq/) which shows you what I mean. The problem here is that it only gives you the position of your child element in pixels, ie. `left: 100px; top: 40px;`.

In the exact same example I would need it to calculate which margin in percentage, ie. `margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 10%;`. I would need to get the div in the final position.

Is this possible to do in JS/jQuery? I couldn't find any examples on how to do this, neither did I have any clue how this could be done so I hope you guys can figure this out.

So the final result should be that if I calulated the percentage of margin right, the div with the position in pixels and the div with the position in percentage should be on the exact same spot in the parent div.

For the people who dont read comments:

The Idea is that you can drag an child element anywhere you want in a div, then get the position in pixels. calculate that to percentage, then add the margins in percentage, so if you would for example resize the window -> the child element would stay on the right spot because you would use percentage now instead of pixels.

Comment: Wouldn't the margin always be the same? Because dragging the element would only change the `top` and `left` position but not the `margin` value.

Comment: yeah this is the problem im facing. for example: if I drag a element in a div it gives me the position in pixels like `left:30px; top20px`; Good but now I would need to calculate those 30px to the percentage I would need if I want to position this child element only by using `margin-left; margin.top`. And this is the problem. How can I calculate that? The final result should be the div with pixels and the div with only margin should be on the exact same spot.

Comment: Can you show us your code to see what you've already tried and what the desired result would be. Also, what's the reason behind using `margin` instead of `top` and `left`? I assume the element will be positioned relatively to the parent?

Comment: Sadly I dont even have any example code of what I have tried, because I have no clue on how I could even do this. Yeah you are right the element will be positioned rlatively to the parent. The Idea is that you can drag an child element anywhere you want in a div, then get the position in pixels. calculate that to percentage, then add the margins in percentage, so if you would for example resize the window -> the child element would stay on the right spot because you would use percentage now instead of pixels.

Comment: But still, why bother using `margin` when you can just use `left` to achieve the same thing? `left: 10%;` is going to do the same thing as `margin-left: 10%;` in this case, surely?

Comment: ah yes your right sorry about that. But Im stuck on calculating the percentage anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to start by recommending using `top` and `left` as your positioning properties. In your case you want to position an element *relative* to the parent. Using `top` and `left` can do that perfectly without any side effects.

`margin` is primarily used to indicate the space between siblings, and also for positioning in a parent, for example when using Flexbox or CSS Grid, and can have some unexpected behavior like bleeding through the parent.

## Calculate relative Top and Left in %.

For this example I'll show you how to calculate the values from pixels into percentages. To do this you must know **how large** the parent is and **where** the child is. First select both the parent and the child.

```
// Select the parent and child elements.
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var child = document.getElementById('child');
```

Get the dimensions of the parent element. `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` indicate the size of the element as seen on the screen in pixels.

```
var parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
var parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;
```

Then get the position of the child *relative* to the parent. `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` are the calculated positions in pixels of the child in relation to the parent element. Almost similar to the `top` and `left` values in CSS.

```
var childOffsetTop = child.offsetTop;
var childOffsetLeft = child.offsetLeft;
```

Now you have the **dimensions** of the parent and the **position** of the child.
Divide the position on each axis (X: left & width, Y: top & height) by the size of the parent to calculate the fraction. Multiply the fraction by 100 and you'll have the value in percentage.

```
var childOffsetTopPercentage = (childOffsetTop / parentHeight) * 100;
var childOffsetLeftPercentage = (childOffsetLeft / parentWidth) * 100;
```

This gives you the `top` and `left` values in percentages.
Set the values to child element to replace the pixel value to percentage. Don't forget to prepend the `'%'` string after the value to make it a percentage value.

```
child.style.top = childOffsetTopPercentage + '%';
child.style.left = childOffsetLeftPercentage + '%';
```